# Connecting a CMOS pin with ADC or DAC

Tags: fpga, layout

In my new project I am using a FPGA and DAC. The DACs CMOS inputs are connected to the pins of the FPGA which are also CMOS compatible.
My question is can I just simply connect the CMOS pins of the DAC with the pins of the FPGA or should I place a resistor in between them?

The distance between the DAC and FPGA is around 1 inch. The frequency of the datapins is max. 20kHz. The voltage level is 3.3V.

In the [schematic of the Arty S7 50 FPGA board from XILINX](https://reference.digilentinc.com/_media/reference/programmable-logic/arty-s7/arty_s7_sch-rev_b.pdf) there are 200 Ohm resistor placed infront of the GPIOs. But do I actually need them?
What is the purpose of this 200 Ohm resistors?

Comment: Frequency of signals? Voltage levels? Physical distance between FPGA and DAC?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson distance is around 1 inch. Voltage levels 3.3V. Frequency is around 20kHz

Comment: Put all of this information into the question itself, not in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are hardwired connections (rather than to a connector that might be misused) then you shouldn't need the resistors at 20 kHz and 3.3V.

Comment: Thank you for your aswer. Do you also know why they placed the 200 Ohm resistor in the schematic?

Comment: My guess is that they were providing some protection from short circuits and improper voltages if the wrong thing was plugged in to one of the connectors. Series resistors can also improve signal waveforms for very high speed connections, but that's a little outside my area of expertise.